# Django cannot download .docx file in Ajax

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have a script directs to the badownload function for downloading a [.docx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) file. The result of this function is a downloaded .docx file, but it didn't work.

Here is the script.

```
   <script>
    $("#download_draft").click(function(){
        $("#download_draft").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#download_draft").text("Saving Data....");
        var json_data={};
        $(".input_data").each(function(){
            var value=$(this).val();
            var parent_html=$(this).parent();
            parent_html.html(value);
            $(this).remove();
        });
        var jenis_ba = $('#id_jenis_ba').val();
        json_data['jenis_ba'] = jenis_ba;
        var nomor= $('#id_nomor').val();
        json_data['nomor'] = nomor;
        var tanggal = $('#id_tanggal').val();
        json_data['tanggal'] = tanggal;
        var judul = $('#id_judul').val();
        json_data['judul'] = judul;
        var keterangan = $('#keterangan').val();
        json_data['keterangan'] = keterangan;

        var json_tim = [];
        $("tbody tr").each(function(row, tr){
            json_tim[row] = {
                'nama_tim' : $(tr).find('td:eq(0) input').val(),
                'nip_tim' : $(tr).find('td:eq(1) input').val()
            }
        });

        json_data['tim'] = json_tim;

        var string_data=JSON.stringify(json_data);

        const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{  download_draft }}',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{data:string_data},
            success: function(data) {
                badownload(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function() {
                $("#download_draft").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#download_draft").text("Download Draft");
            }
        });

        function badownload(result){
            $.ajax({
                url: '../../berita-acara/badownload',
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
                type:'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{data:result.result},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('sukses');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(url);
                },
            })
        }

    });
    </script>
```

This is the function. It has to download the *download.docx* file, but it didn't work:

```
class BeritaAcaraBA(View):
    def post(self, request):
        .....
        ......
        .......
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=download.docx'
        document.save(response)
        return response
```

I try to download a .docx file from the *badownload* function, but it didn't work with Ajax. I am new in Django.

Comment: Re *"it didn't work"*: Can you reveal more? E.g., in what way didn't it work? Was there an error message? An empty file?

Answer (score 0):

If the file already exists on the file server, then ready it for downloading.

```
import os
from django.http import HttpResponse

class BeritaAcaraBA(View):
    def post(self, request):
        filepath = os.path.abspath(r"path\to\file.docx")
        if os.path.exists(filepath):
            with open(filepath, 'rb') as worddoc:
                content = worddoc.read()
                response = HttpResponse(content,content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=download.docx'
                response['Content-Length'] = len(content) #
                return response
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Failed to Download")
```

In the success function of the script, create a hidden `<a>` element with the file URL that is received from the response. Append it to the document body and make a click event which will start downloading the file.

```
function badownload(result){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../berita-acara/badownload',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{data:result.result},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('sukses');
            const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = data.file_url;
            downloadLink.download = 'download.docx';
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(url);
        },
    })
}
```

Comment: I have tried it. It didn't work