# Download a CSV file using Ajax in Django - saved file contains the view content instead of the CSV content

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm dynamically generating a CSV file from some content, and want to provide a message to the user and then download the file.

When using JavaScript, the file that's downloaded is the HTML content of the view, and not the CSV file. If I remove the JavaScript code, the CSV file is downloaded, but then there isn't any indication of this to the user.

How can I get the CSV when using JavaScript?

One thing I note is that I see a `GET` after the `POST` in my Django application log when using the JavaScript  script.

I am following *[How to create CSV output](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/outputting-csv/)* to generate the CSV content, and got the JavaScript code from the answer in *[Django cannot download .docx file in Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76192288/django-cannot-download-docx-file-in-ajax)*.

This view content works when used without the JavaScript components - a CSV file is downloaded.

```
def csv_report(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        report_dates_form = AllMemberseventForm(request.POST)
        if report_dates_form.is_valid():
            start_date = report_dates_form.cleaned_data.get("start_date")
            end_date = report_dates_form.cleaned_data.get("end_date")
            events = Events.objects.filter(event_date__range=[start_date, end_date]).order_by("event_date")
            if events and len(events) > 0:
                response = HttpResponse(
                    content_type="text/csv",
                    headers={
                        "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename,
                        "filename": filename,
                        "event_count": len(events),
                    },
                )
                writer = csv.writer(response)
                for event in events:
                    writer.writerow(
                        [event.thing, event.otherthing, event.event_date]
                    )
                return response
```

My javascript in the template that the view uses is as follows. In my chrome developer tools console, the expected CSV content is shown when I log the data entry. The HTML is updated with the result content prepended below.

```
$('#post-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    get_event_reports_csv();
});

function get_event_reports_csv() {
    let start_date = $('#id_start_date').val()
    let end_date = $('#id_end_date').val()
    console.log(`Getting all report for all events between ${start_date} and ${end_date}`)
    $.ajax({
        url : "/signin/event_reports/", // my view
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : {
            start_date : $('#id_start_date').val(),
            end_date : $('#id_end_date').val(),
        }, // data sent with the post request

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(data, textStatus, request) {
            var filename = request.getResponseHeader('filename');
            var event_count = request.getResponseHeader('event_count');

            console.log("Request for all events report successful");
            if (event_count == 1) {
                $("#result").prepend(`There was ${event_count} events between ${start_date} and ${end_date}. The CSV file will be downloaded shortly. Please check your downloads folder.`);
            } else {
                $("#result").prepend(`There were ${event_count} events between ${start_date} and ${end_date}. The CSV file will be downloaded shortly. Please check your downloads folder.`);
            }

            console.log(`data: ${data}`)
            const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.href = data;
            downloadLink.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
  var filename = request.getResponseHeader('filename');
  var event_count = request.getResponseHeader('event_count');
  
  console.log("Request for all events report successful");
  if (event_count == 1) {
    $("#result").prepend(`There was ${event_count} event between ${start_date} and ${end_date}. The CSV file will be downloaded shortly. Please check your downloads folder.`);
  } else {
    $("#result").prepend(`There were ${event_count} events between ${start_date} and ${end_date}. The CSV file will be downloaded shortly. Please check your downloads folder.`);
  }

  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.href = url;
  downloadLink.download = filename;
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

  URL.revokeObjectURL(url); // Clean up the URL object to release memory
}
```

By creating a Blob object and using URL.createObjectURL(), you ensure that the downloaded content corresponds to the CSV data received from the server. Additionally, I added the URL.revokeObjectURL(url) statement to release the memory associated with the created URL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Victoria Hill!

All six of your answers here appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was getting the "code 414, message Request-URI Too Long" error and this Blob save me. Have a good day.